# Nuxt/Vue - trying to display a user list based on gender

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am pretty new with both Nuxt and Vue, and need help with a dilemma. I am currently displaying a list of users and their information from my database, but I would like to be able to filter the user list by their gender via a drop down - either male, female or both.

As mentioned, the user lists is being displayed, but I am stuck regarding to get the filtering to work.

This is what I have:

**matches.vue**

```
<form>
    <select id="search" type="text" v-model="search" v-on:change="updateGender" class="flex items-center font-sans mt-12 lg:mt-2 px-2">
        <option value="">Search by gender</option>
        <option value="Mand">Male</option>
        <option value="Kvinde">Female</option>
     </select>
</form>

<tbody class="text-gray-600 text-sm font-light">
    <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id"  class="border-b border-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-100">
        <td class="py-3 px-6 text-left whitespace-nowrap">
            <div class="flex items-center">
                {{user.firstName}} {{ user.lastName}}
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="py-3 px-6 text-left">
            <div class="flex items-center">
                {{user.gender}}
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="py-3 px-6 text-center">
            <div class="flex items-center justify-center">
                {{user.age}}    
            </div>
        </td>   
    </tr>  
</tbody>

<script>


export default {
    data() {
        return {
            search: '',
            users: [],
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$axios
        .get('/api/users/all')
        .then(response => {
            this.users = response.data;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            throw err;
        });
    },
    methods: {
        async updateGender() {
            try {
                await this.$axios.
                    post('/api/users/filterAll', {
                        search: this.search
                    })
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.search = response.data;
                    })
            } catch (err) {
                throw new Error(err)
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

router.js

```
// Get all Users
router.get(
    '/api/users/all', 
    UserController.getAll 
)

// For filtering all Users
router.post(
    '/api/users/filterAll', 
    UserController.getAll 
)
```

controllers/User.js

```
exports.getAll  = async (req, res) => {
    let users = await models.User.findAll();
    let allUsers = users;
    res.json(allUsers);
}
```

As of now, I am not getting any errors, but I have absolutely no idea on how to get this to work. Can anyone help me getting closer to a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check your controllers/User.js. The  '/api/users/filterAll' route is calling getAll but it isn't filtering the results based on search body criteria posted from Axios.